# Central AC sometimes doesn't cool

Tags: hvac

Occasionally, my central AC, both inside and outside units being Lennox, stops cooling and blows only fan. The outside unit's fan does run. The air blowing is not cooled and the fat pipe near the air handler (inside unit) is not cold, like it is when it works fine. This happens only sometimes and mostly it works fine.

Can you guess the reason for this behavior?

Comment: Sounds like the evaporator is freezing up, compressor running and not much cooling. Low freon charge or dirty coils can cause this happen.

Comment: I just opened the inside unit to look at the coils and they are not frozen. is that what the evaporator is ? I'm not using freon but a different refrigerant that comes in pink tanks

Comment: I'm going to have to guess that if you identify your refrigerant by the color of the tank you probably should leave the A/C servicing to someone actually licensed to handle refrigerants.

Comment: I wasn't going to try to refill the refrigerant myself anyway. Was wondering if it's something other than that

Comment: If it is a newer system r410 is a pink tank. There should be some numbers on it. I have not worked with 410 but remember it is really high pressure so a leak could cause low cooling. A  service call sounds in order. I have had some problems with the newer higher pressure  mixes that I never saw with R12 or R22. Better to get it checked out by a licensed shop or tech.

Comment: Yeah. The system is only in its 3rd summer

Comment: Well like I mentioned no experiance with 410 but believe it is the highest pressure gass from my last class a while back. I have and do need to keep tabs on several 404 systems and 134. Both require more maintenance than 12 or 22. That have much lower pressures.

Comment: What's the outdoor temperature, and the indoor set point when this happens? What's the model number of both units?  Is this a heat pump and air handler, or furnace and condensing unit? Does it tend to happen more often when the system has been running a long time, or on really hot days?  Is the condensing unit in a shaded area, or in direct sun?

Comment: It was about 80 F outside last night when it happened with the thermostat being set to about 72.  I don't have the model numbers on me but it's not a heat pump but just an indoor air handler with an outside condensing unit.  The system does only AC, not heat. I think 2.5 or 3 ton.

Comment: The first thing to check is always  the charge. Unfortunately, most homeowners do not have the equipment, knowledge, or proper certifications to do this themselves.  You'll likely have to call in an HVAC technician to diagnose the problem.  I'm guessing that the compressor is turning off due to overheating, but there's no easy way to say why from an internet away. Could be low refrigerant, worn out compressor, inadequate airflow through the condensing unit, inadequate airflow through the evaporator, etc.

Comment: I am very handy and I have a ton of tools that are beyond "homeowner competence" and know how to use them.  i wouldn't mind to acquire gauges to check the pressure if i can easily learn to use them